# java - Error 406 on web Application

Tags: java, json, rest

I'm developing a web application using different APIs to fetch information from some sites. But one of them is getting me this error when trying to use a search method I have created (The only one using this API).

```
org.restlet.resource.ResourceException: OK (406) - The resource identified by the request is only capable of generating response entities which have content characteristics not acceptable according to the accept headers sent in the request
at org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.doError(ClientResource.java:592)
at org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.handleInbound(ClientResource.java:1153)
at org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.handle(ClientResource.java:1008)
at org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.handle(ClientResource.java:946)
at org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.get(ClientResource.java:660)
at aiss.model.resource.KitsuResources.getBusqueda(KitsuResources.java:28)
at aiss.controller.SearchController.doGet(SearchController.java:34)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
at com.google.appengine.api.socket.dev.DevSocketFilter.doFilter(DevSocketFilter.java:74)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ResponseRewriterFilter.doFilter(ResponseRewriterFilter.java:128)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:34)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:63)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:48)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:122)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:366)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectModuleRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:349)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doFilter(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:116)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:95)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:508)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:547)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
```

This is the log that the console returns when trying to use the method.
The failure should be at a class called KitsuResources, when It tries to create a object of the class "Example":
Class KitsuResources:

```
public class KitsuResources {

private static final String URL_Kitsu = "https://kitsu.io/api/edge";
private static final String searchPath = "/anime?filter[text]=%QUERY&page[limit]=5&page[offset]=5&fields[anime]=titles";

public Example getBusqueda(String query) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {

 String search = URLEncoder.encode(query, "UTF-8");

 ClientResource cr = null;
 Example busquedaAnime = null;
 try {

 cr = new ClientResource(URL_Kitsu + searchPath.replace("%QUERY", search));
 busquedaAnime = cr.get(Example.class);
 } catch (ResourceException e) {
     throw e;
 }

     return busquedaAnime;
 }}
```

Class Example:

```
package aiss.kitsu;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnyGetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnySetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonPropertyOrder;

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({
"data",
"meta",
"links"
})
public class Example {

@JsonProperty("data")
private List<Datum> data = null;
@JsonProperty("meta")
private Meta meta;
@JsonProperty("links")
private Links_ links;
@JsonIgnore
private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();

@JsonProperty("data")
public List<Datum> getData() {
    return data;
}

@JsonProperty("data")
public void setData(List<Datum> data) {
    this.data = data;
}

public Example withData(List<Datum> data) {
    this.data = data;
    return this;
}

@JsonProperty("meta")
public Meta getMeta() {
    return meta;
}

@JsonProperty("meta")
public void setMeta(Meta meta) {
    this.meta = meta;
}

public Example withMeta(Meta meta) {
    this.meta = meta;
    return this;
}

@JsonProperty("links")
public Links_ getLinks() {
    return links;
}

@JsonProperty("links")
public void setLinks(Links_ links) {
    this.links = links;
}

public Example withLinks(Links_ links) {
    this.links = links;
    return this;
}

@JsonAnyGetter
public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
    return this.additionalProperties;
}

@JsonAnySetter
public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
    this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
}

public Example withAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
    this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
    return this;
}}
```

This is the controller that starts the petition and gets the response deserialized:

```
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import aiss.kitsu.Example;
import aiss.model.resource.KitsuResources;

public class SearchController extends HttpServlet {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(SearchController.class.getName());


public SearchController() {
    super();
}
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String query = request.getParameter("searchQuery");
    RequestDispatcher rd = null;

    KitsuResources aniL = new KitsuResources();
    Example resultado = aniL.getBusqueda(query);

    if (resultado!=null){
        request.setAttribute("data", resultado);
        rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/resultados.jsp");


    } else {
        log.log(Level.SEVERE, "Kitsu object: " + resultado);
        rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/error.jsp");
    }
    rd.forward(request, response);
}


protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    doGet(request, response);
}}
```

My pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>0.0.1</version>

<groupId>aiss</groupId>
<artifactId>AniRat</artifactId>

<!-- Restlet repository -->
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>maven-restlet</id>
        <name>Restlet repository</name>
        <url>https://maven.restlet.com</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>



<properties>
    <appengine.version>1.9.46</appengine.version>   <!-- AppEngine version -->
    <servlet.version>2.5</servlet.version>  <!-- Servlet version -->
    <jslt.version>1.2</jslt.version>    <!-- JSLT version -->
    <restlet.version>2.3.7</restlet.version> <!-- Restlet version -->
    <resteasy.version>2.3.5.Final</resteasy.version> <!-- RESTEasy version -->
    <jackson.version>2.8.2</jackson.version> <!-- Jackson version -->
    <google.client.version>1.20.0</google.client.version> <!-- Google HTTP Client version -->
    <junit.version>4.12</junit.version> <!-- JUnit version -->
    <mockito.version>2.0.2-beta</mockito.version> <!-- Mockito version -->
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
    <maven.compiler.showDeprecation>true</maven.compiler.showDeprecation>
    <archiveClasses>true</archiveClasses>
</properties>

<prerequisites>
    <maven>3.3.9</maven>
</prerequisites>

<dependencies>
    <!-- Compile/runtime dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
        <artifactId>appengine-api-1.0-sdk</artifactId>
        <version>${appengine.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>${servlet.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>${jslt.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Test Dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
        <version>${mockito.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
<!--Json Dependencies -->
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.restlet.jee</groupId> 
 <artifactId>org.restlet.ext.json</artifactId>
  <version>${restlet.version}</version> 
  </dependency>

    <!-- Jackson 2 core -->
    <dependency>
<groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
<artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
<version>2.4.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
<artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
<version>2.4.1.1</version>
</dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.restlet.jse</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.restlet.ext.jackson</artifactId>
        <version>${restlet.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- RESTEasy -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>${resteasy.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-jackson-provider</artifactId>
        <version>${resteasy.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Google HTTP Client Library -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.http-client</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-http-client</artifactId>
        <version>${google.client.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Google HTTP Client Library (AppEngine extension) -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.http-client</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-http-client-appengine</artifactId>
        <version>${google.client.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Jackson module for Google HTTP Client -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.http-client</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-http-client-jackson2</artifactId>
        <version>${google.client.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Google OAuth Client Library -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.oauth-client</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-oauth-client-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>${google.client.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
<groupId>com.graphql-java</groupId>
<artifactId>graphql-java</artifactId>
<version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>com.graphql-java</groupId>
<artifactId>graphql-java-tools</artifactId>
<version>3.2.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>com.graphql-java</groupId>
<artifactId>graphql-java-servlet</artifactId>
<version>4.0.0</version>
</dependency>



</dependencies>

<build>

    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}/WEB-INF/classes</outputDirectory>
    <plugins>

        <!-- Maven AppEngine plugin -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${appengine.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <enableJarClasses>false</enableJarClasses>
                <version>${app.version}</version>
                <!-- Comment in the below snippet to bind to all IPs instead of just 
                    localhost -->
                <!-- <address>0.0.0.0</address> -->
                <port>8090</port>
                <!-- Comment in the below snippet to enable local debugging with a remote 
                    debugger like those included with Eclipse or IntelliJ -->
                <jvmFlags>
                    <jvmFlag>-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=n</jvmFlag>
                </jvmFlags>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <!-- Hot reload of Java and static files (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21345177/is-there-any-way-to-trigger-the-maven-appengine-devserver-to-auto-refresh-static) -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.7</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>process-classes</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <target>
                            <property name="target.webapp.dir"
                                value="${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}" />
                            <property name="src.webapp.dir" value="${basedir}/src/main/webapp" />

                            <sync verbose="true" todir="${target.webapp.dir}"
                                includeEmptyDirs="true">
                                <fileset dir="${src.webapp.dir}" />
                                <preserveintarget>
                                    <include name="WEB-INF/lib/**" />
                                    <include name="WEB-INF/classes/**" />
                                    <include name="WEB-INF/appengine-generated/**" />
                                </preserveintarget>
                            </sync>

                            <!-- <sync verbose="true" todir="${target.webapp.dir}/WEB-INF/classes"> 
                                <fileset dir="${basedir}/target/classes" /> </sync> -->

                        </target>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <!-- Code Coverage report generation -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.7.9</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>generate-code-coverage-report</id>
                    <phase>test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>report</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <!-- Hot reload of Java and static files (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21345177/is-there-any-way-to-trigger-the-maven-appengine-devserver-to-auto-refresh-static) -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                        <pluginExecutions>
                            <pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                                    <versionRange>[1.6,)</versionRange>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>run</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <action>
                                    <execute>
                                        <runOnIncremental>true</runOnIncremental>
                                    </execute>
                                </action>
                            </pluginExecution>
                        </pluginExecutions>
                    </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
</project>
```

What would be the problem? It seems like the JSON returned it's not deserializing well.

Edit 1: Adding controller
Edit 2: Adding pom.xml
Edit 3:

The new error code after apply the purposed solution:

```
Internal Connector Error (1002) - No available client connector supports the required protocol: 'HTTPS'. Please add the JAR of a matching connector to your classpath.
at org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.doError(ClientResource.java:612)
at org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.handleInbound(ClientResource.java:1203)
at org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.handle(ClientResource.java:1027)
at org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.handle(ClientResource.java:969)
at org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.get(ClientResource.java:680)
at aiss.model.resource.KitsuResources.getBusqueda(KitsuResources.java:36)
at aiss.controller.SearchController.doGet(SearchController.java:33)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
at com.google.appengine.api.socket.dev.DevSocketFilter.doFilter(DevSocketFilter.java:74)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ResponseRewriterFilter.doFilter(ResponseRewriterFilter.java:128)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:34)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:63)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:48)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:122)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:366)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectModuleRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:349)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doFilter(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:116)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:95)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:508)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:547)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
```

Comment: Check my edited answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your API return JSON but your request does not specify it wants JSON back, so the media negotiation failed.

Put this after you declare your request:

```
cr = new ClientResource(URL_Kitsu + searchPath.replace("%QUERY", search));
MediaType custom = MediaType.register("application/vnd.api+json", "application/vnd.api+json");
Engine.getInstance().getRegisteredConverters().add(new JsonConverter()); // In your application, this should be done when start up the app instead of here
cr.accept(custom);  // This tell your server you want JSON
busquedaAnime = cr.get(Example.class);
```

**Edit**

After checking by postman, I saw that the API generate `application/vnd.api+json` data only. So you should add that as your `Accept` header

**Edit 2:**

Add JSON converter dependency (for maven)

```
<dependency>        
    <groupId>org.restlet.jee</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.restlet.ext.json</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.7</version>
</dependency>
```

**Edit 3:**

Add this for HTTPS:

```
<dependency>  
   <groupId>org.restlet.jse</groupId>  
   <artifactId>org.restlet</artifactId>  
   <version>2.3.7</version>  
</dependency>  
<dependency>  
   <groupId>org.restlet.jse</groupId>  
   <artifactId>org.restlet.ext.simple</artifactId>  
   <version>2.3.7</version>  
</dependency>
```

In the doc: https://restlet.com/open-source/documentation/user-guide/2.2/core/security/https

> In addition to the standard Restlet jar files, you also need to
>   reference jar files for HTTPS. The 'Simple' HTTPS connector uses these
>   jar files:
>
> lib/org.restlet.ext.simple_3.1.jar\
>
> lib/org.simpleframework_3.1/org.simpleframework.jar
>
> lib/org.restlet.ext.ssl.jar\
>
> lib/org.jsslutils_0.5/org.jsslutils.jar

**Edit 4**

After hours of digging your code, I found that you're mixing dependencies and have too many conflicting libraries.

1. Remove all dependencies of `.restlet.` group.
2. Change the `restlet.version` to `2.2-M6` (somehow `JacksonConverter` cannot be initialized in newer version because of packaging change. I can't figure it out yet so use the older version)
3. Add these dependencies for working with HTTPs and JSON:

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.restlet.jee</groupId>
       <artifactId>org.restlet.ext.net</artifactId>
       <version>2.2-M6</version>
       <exclusions>
           <exclusion> // If you use other version that your restlet then you should exclude it, otherwise some strange runtime class conflicting will occur
               <groupId>org.restlet.jee</groupId>
               <artifactId>org.restlet</artifactId>
           </exclusion>
       </exclusions>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.restlet.jee</groupId>
       <artifactId>org.restlet</artifactId>
       <version>${restlet.version}</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.restlet.jee</groupId>
       <artifactId>org.restlet.ext.jackson</artifactId>
       <version>${restlet.version}</version>
   </dependency>
   ```
4. Because we want to handle custom json format, but default jackson does not support it so we have to define our custom converter:

   ```
   public class CustomJacksonConverter extends JacksonConverter {
    private static final ObjectMapper OBJECT_MAPPER = new ObjectMapper();

    @Override
    public <T> float score(Representation source, Class<T> target, Resource resource) {
        // Restlet will use this function to determine which converter to be use. We yeild 1.0F equals to say: I will handle it from here
        if (source.getMediaType().getName().contains("json")) {
           return 1.0F;
        }
        return super.score(source, target, resource);
    }

    @Override
    public <T> T toObject(Representation source, Class<T> target, Resource resource) throws IOException {
       // Write stream to object
       return OBJECT_MAPPER.readValue(source.getStream(), target);
    }
   ```

   }
5. Register custom json converter and media type

   ```
   MediaType custom = MediaType.register("application/vnd.api+json", "application/vnd.api+json");
   cr.accept(custom);
   Engine.getInstance().getRegisteredConverters().add(new CustomJacksonConverter());
   ```
6. Enjoy

   ```
   busquedaAnime = cr.get(Example.class);
   ```

**Edit 7**

After working with this library, I recommend you to switch to another client.

One of my favorite is `Retrofit`.

It will relieve you from the pain of HTTPs dependencies, media negotiation... etc

Comment: It's finally working, thanks a lot. As for the libs, I use the ones provided by my homeroom teacher, so sadly I can't use other ones than restlet.

Comment: I must admit that to debug this application is a pain in the *ss haha